# Finite-dimensional representations of DAHA of rank 1

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras

DAHA of rank 1 is defined by the relation
$$
(T - t^{1/2})(T + t^{-1/2})=0~, \quad TXT=X^{-1}~, \quad TY^{-1}T=Y~, \quad 
Y^{-1}X^{-1}YXT^2q^{1/2}=1
.$$
To understand its representations, it is useful to introduce non-symmetric polynomials $e_n(x)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$e_n(x)\equiv X^n \quad \textrm{mod} \ X^m \prec X^n ~, \quad Ye_n=q^{-n_\sharp}e_n~.$$
See Eqn. (2.6.1) of [Cherednik's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=zFiWU0rHmXMC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=double+affine+hecke+algebra&ots=520bosblHB&sig=7bzCayiN3cY5Ix3WpQkk8uFrEqM#v=onepage&q&f=false). In addition, there are operations
$$
1=e_0\xrightarrow{A_0}e_1\xrightarrow{B_1}e_{-1}\xrightarrow{A_{-1}}e_2\xrightarrow{B_2}e_{-2}\xrightarrow{A_{-2}}\cdots
$$
See Corollary 2.6.1 of [Cherednik's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=zFiWU0rHmXMC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=double+affine+hecke+algebra&ots=520bosblHB&sig=7bzCayiN3cY5Ix3WpQkk8uFrEqM#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more detail.

In sec 2.8.2 of [Cherednik's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=zFiWU0rHmXMC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=double+affine+hecke+algebra&ots=520bosblHB&sig=7bzCayiN3cY5Ix3WpQkk8uFrEqM#v=onepage&q&f=false), he mentions that there are finite-dimensional representations of DAHA of rank 1 when $t = - q^{-n/2}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ (Eqn. (2.8.11)). As far as I understand, the convention throughout the book is $t=q^k$. Hence, my first question is:

In this case, can one consider $k=-n/2+\log_q(-1)$?

Then, after Eqn. (2.8.11), it says that
\begin{equation}
T(e_{-n})=t^{1/2} e_{-n} \quad   \textrm{and} \quad  s(e_{-n})=e_{-n} \quad (**)     
\end{equation}
My second question is how one can obtain this formula? It seems to me that if I use the definition of B_n (Corollary 2.6.1)
$$
B_n = t^{1/2} (T + \frac{t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}}{t q^n-1}) \quad \textrm{for}\quad n>0
$$
$$
B_{-n} = t^{1/2} (T + \frac{t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}}{t^{-1} q^{-n}-1})   \quad \textrm{for}\quad n>0~,
$$
I got
$$
e_{-n} = t^{1/2} (T - t^{1/2}) e_n \quad   \textrm{and} \quad (T + t^{-1/2}) e_{-n} =0
$$
as in sec 2.8.1. I cannot see how the condition of Eqn. (2.8.11) change the situation from sec 2.8.1. I wonder if somebody could possibly tell me how to derive  $(**)$ by using Eqn. (2.8.11).